# Как записать данные в столбец mysql с типом данных enum средствами java?

Tags: java, mysql

В базе данных в таблице data есть столбец users с типом данных enum, в котором содержится перечисление.
Как внести данные в этот столбец?

Пример запроса:

```
String sql = "UPDATE data SET `users`=? WHERE `name`=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connect().prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setЧТО-ТО() //На этом моменте ступор
stmt.setString(2, user.toLowerCase());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

К уже имеющимся либо пустому столбцу типа enum следует добавить перечисление. Никак не могу разобраться.

Comment: также setString, либо создаете свой enum Users и выполняете 
`stmt.setString(1, Users.USER1.toString())`